# ssh connection from Mac OS X shows ">" prompt and stays there

Tags: linux, macos, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

**Problem** -  when I try to connect to an Amazon AWS EC2 linux instance through SSH, instead of connecting, it simply shows a `>` prompt as if asking for more info.

command entered through terminal
`ssh -i “<private_key_path>" <user>@<host_address>`

when i hit enter, it just shows a
`>`
prompt. there are no errors, or messages. Just that single prompt which accepts anything i write. so probably asking for more input.

I had connected to the EC2 instance yesterday (using this exact code) and it worked then. so the command itself is correct, including username, host address, private key file, etc. It has to be something else with the OS. Between then and now, I dont remember making any significant change to the system. The only change i can think of was a week back when I reset my PATH variable to fix a problem.

My current $PATH output
`//anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: No such file or directory`

I have already searched on google and stackoverflow, but didnt find any previously asked questions along this line. Also I am new to ssh and linux (having worked on windows for the past 15 years). so there might be something really simple that I am just not aware of.

Comment: Did you try to debug your ssh command using `ssh -vvv .../...`?

Comment: Try giving it a single quote `'` or a double quote `"` to complete whatever it is looking for.

Comment: yes Mark. that worked. the two double quotes somehow look similar but are not. any idea what the other double quote is?

Comment: @molivier 
though this particular problem is resolved, i will keep the debug option in mind. thank you

Comment: question for any of the moderators. now that I found a solution to my question, do I delete this post? or just let it be (either by providing my own resolution or leaving this in its current state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:
Please do not quote the identity file path.

Comment: thanks Furhan. 
i started doing some random experiments and looks like it is  two different type of quotes around the private-key. i retyped the two quotes to match each other and now it works. any idea what that other double quote at the beginning is. and how it could have been typed from a keyboard. they look almost the same though

Comment: @AsitM happens all the time. If you copy paste it from some word processor or web page, it translates into this look-a-like quote character :)

Comment: since the problem was with the quotes surrounding the private key (though matching quotes can still work with the private key), I am marking your answer is correct. Thank you.

Comment: This is not the correct answer if AWS firewall rejects IP or SSHd is not working address it gives connection time out and not  ">" prompt

Comment: @error2007s for this question, it is the right answer. I copied the connection string from aws, and while editing replaced the end quotation with a double quote from keyboard. because of which the terminal showed '>' prompt expecting to find an ending double quote. Furhan's second suggestion regarding removing the quotes fixed it.

Comment: @AsitM First 2 scenarios is wrong direction for the Stack Overflow users he should just remove the first two parts from the answers

Comment: @error2007s edited my answer. Was brainstorming. Thnx for pointing it out though:)

Comment: Quoting the file path is not a problem; using the *correct* quotes (ASCII, not Unicode typographic quotes) is necessary, though.